# FFmpeg source files wild card

Tags: ffmpeg

I am joining a series of image files into a movie file with FFmpeg.

Files start at `XYZ00000.PNG`, `XYZ00001.PNG` etc.  I refer to them as `XYZ%05d.PNG` in the FFmpeg command line.

That works fine.

But, if I delete the first (for example) 30 frames so my frame images start at `XYZ00031.PNG` onwards FFmpeg fails to build with an error;

```
[image2 @ 00000000043f2b40] Could find no file with path 'XYZ%05d.PNG' and index in the range 0-4
XYZ%05d.PNG: No such file or directory
```

Is there an alternate wildcard I can use to get FFmpeg to start at whatever the lowest numbered frame is?

If I rename `XYZ00031.PNG` to `XYZ00000.PNG` the build works, but only adds the single first frame.  It ignores the other frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `-start_number`

```
ffmpeg -start_number 30 -framerate 24 -i XYZ%05d.PNG output.mp4
```

From the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

> `start_number`
>   Set the index of the file matched by the image file pattern to start to read from. Default value is 0.

## Or the glob pattern

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i -framerate 10  "*.png" out.mkv
```

This method may not work on Windows.

Comment: start_number still requires the files to start at 0.  It does allow skipping the first n frames.  Rather than delete the files I don;t want added, I will leave them and use start_frame.

Comment: @Some1Else Works for me just fine if the first file in the directory is `img_0030.png` for example.